# Loss of data while storing Spark data frame in parquet format

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, parquet

I have a csv data file which I can load into pyspark:

````
spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local").appName("MYAPP").getOrCreate()```

df = spark.read.csv( path = csvfilepath, sep="|", schema=my_schema, nullValue="NULL", mode="DROPMALFORMED")```
````

Checking the number of rows of the data frame gives approximately 20 millions rows.

```
df.count()
```

I re-store my data frame in parquet:

```
df.write.mode("overwrite").parquet( parquetfilepath )
```

I then load the parquet data:

```
df = spark.read.parquet( parquetfilepath )
```

Now when I count the rows (`df.count()`) I only get 3 million rows.

Why did I lose 85% of the rows and how can I solve this problem? I have also tried to use "repartition" and "coalesce" when creating the parquet data with the same result.

Comment: The code you've posted won't have the result you're describing. Please post your complete code including the filepaths.

Comment: My assumption is that this could something have to do with line feeds that are getting differently interpreted as csv with a schema and parquet. But this is just a guess...

Comment: Thanks for your comment, mike. The csv file has already been loaded and a Spark data frame has been created. So at that point, do line feeds matter?

Comment: What are the values of `csv_ext` and `parquet_ext`?

Comment: @Dave now I have added the missing constants.

Comment: I have tried the same code in Scala and got a similar result. Many many rows of the data are lost. I surely can't be the only one who experiences this problem.


`val DF = spark.read.options( Map( "sep" -> "|", "nullValue" -> "NULL", "mode" -> "DROPMALFORMED")).schema( VarupostSchema ).csv( "C:\\PROFILE_DATA\\Data_Tullverket\\Export\\ExVarupost.txt" )

DF.write.parquet("C:\\TEMP\\ExVarupost.parquet")`

Comment: I have also tried storing the data frame back as csv file.

`df.repartition(1).write.mode('overwrite').csv(path = "C:\\TEMP\\test.csv", sep="|", nullValue="NULL")`

That also gives me the same kind of data loss. Changing the mode from "DROPMALFORMED" doesn't change anything either.

Comment: I get a warning when I run the program which states:

`20/05/25 02:04:48 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable`

From what I have seen online, this warning can be ignored, but now I am starting to wonder if it can have something to do with the problems that I am experiencing.

Answer (score 2):

I am answering my own question as I have now understood what the problem is. It is actually a very simple beginner's mistake. The reason that I lose data is simply because I have asked for it when the df is read with the option mode="DROPMALFORMED". When I count the rows of the date frame I find that it is 20 millions rows, but some of them are inconsistent with the schema and are dropped when the data is actually written down to disk (i.e. the dropping of malformed rows which I requested when reading the csv has been deferred to this point). What I didn't realize was that there were errors in my data.